# What triggers a buying frenzy vs a fully stocked bonus?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

After fully stocking a floor,  sometimes instead of getting a minor bonus, I receive a message saying that a buying frenzy is going on.  To me, it appears to be randomly generated, but what triggers a buying frenzy as appose to fully stocked bonus?
[image]

## VS

[image]

Comment: Excellent question, as always, BTW . . .

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this, and first of all, your screenshot shows that the "Fully Stocked" bonus *is* the buying frenzy, and that's what I've seen...there's only 1 type of bonus possible.  I believe this works the same way as in Tiny Tower, where you get a bux for a Fully Stocked floor.

What I've seen is that this will happen with floors that have all 3 items nearly fully stocked, but it will also happen when 1 of the items is nearly full, and another item is nearly empty.  This leads me to believe that the trigger is something like: if 3 items stocked & at least 2 items > 90% stocked, then award fully stocked bonus.  I have yet to see a fully stocked bonus where this hasn't been met.

Comment: From what I have seen, you get a coin bonus (no popup, +coins in the bottom left of your screen) or fully stocked frenzy bonus

Comment: I updated the original question to show both.  The +41 is the coin bonus I got when fully stocked. (didnt get buying frenzy)

Comment: @ZeroStack - I once got an Imperial Bux for fully stocking! I was in such shock-and-awe that I forgot to take a screenshot. But that's possible too.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it to be random.  But, it does seem to primarily happen in my quicker stocked levels.  For example, I see it mostly in Mos Espa Cafe, Workout Center, etc.  Never in say Marriage Center, or Lightsaber Craft.

UPDATE:  Of course, right after writing this I started getting buying frenzies on all levels.

You don't know the power of the dark side . . .

LOL

Comment: +1 `you don't know the power of the darkside` lol, I agree that it is random, but it is possible that the only reason it *seems* that we get them more on fast levels is because they are fast, so we tend to stock them more often!

Comment: Agreed. I thought the same.

Comment: The more you play straight, the more you get buying frenzies because it's related to the amount of stock you have on a floor.  Perhaps there's more leeway on floors with longer stock times...